# if constexpr in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

My short question: Is there something like `if constexpr` in C#?

More explanation: I'm developing a C# app that has a free and a pro version and the pro version is going to have a separate executable.  But all the difference between them in my code is a constant bool:

```
const bool FREE_VERSION = true;
```

some codes are like:

```
if(!FREE_VERSION)...
```

In C++, with `if constexpr` such code is not compiled at all so there is no way to hack the executable.

Is there any similar feature in C# so that I can be sure that the pro version code does not exist in the final  free-version executable?

Comment: you can use [if directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if)

Comment: If `#if` isn't enough, you'll need to write a source file in your build script. Or inline in the build using https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/.

Comment: No. `constexpr` is basically running C++ code at compile time. In .NET, "compile" is basically a lex/parse phase that generates IL. The real work happens in the runtime. There's no benefit to be had here. You can use `#if` or a preprocessor to strip out the code but, honestly, no one is going to bother disassembling your app to get around this. We use C# to preprocess and produce both C# and C++ in our builds. It works, but it takes a bit of tweaking to get to work correctly.

Comment: Or you can add conditional compilation to your project file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditional-constructs?view=vs-2019 to exclude whole files / folders / project references.

Comment: It is much better to use conditional compilation. That said, @3Dave is incorrect to imply that C# compilers don't optimize out branches that are verifiable as not taken at compile time. I.e. if you write `if (false) { /* do something */ }`, any code in the block i.e. `/* do something */` does not wind up in the compiled assembly. This is true with the C# 8 compiler even for Debug builds (I didn't bother to double-check earlier compiler versions).

Comment: @PeterDuniho So `if` will be `if constexpr` whenever possible?

Comment: _"`if` will be `if constexpr` whenever possible?"_ -- yes, basically. C# does not have something strictly equivalent to `constexpr` (especially as when applied to functions), but it does automatically infer compile-time constant expressions, and when you use such expressions you can rely on the fact that they are understood at compile time. Frankly, it's not really clear in your question why you are focusing on `constexpr`, as this is not technically part of your code example. You just have a regular literal value, and the compiler would omit code based on that even in versions before C++11.

Comment: While not directly applicable to your question, you may find this discussion regarding whether to include a feature like `constexpr` to C#. A notable point is that `constexpr` is, in part, used to address issues in C++ code that simply don't come up in C# (e.g. because C# doesn't have templates).

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks. `if constexpr` guarantees explicitly that the code will not be compiled in C++. I thought there may be something like that in C#. C# executable can be reversed easily. Not safe.

Comment: _"Not safe"_ -- you seem to be missing the point. C# won't include code it can verify at compile time won't be executed. And if you're at all worried about that, the fact that the IL C# is compiled to is so much easier to read and decompile means that it's trivial for you to verify that the compiler is doing what you want. In any case, you shouldn't be relying on constant-expression `if` statements; use conditional compilation...that's the correct feature to use for this type of situation, whether in C, C++, or C#.